# How to require an approval from at least one code owner from each group

Tags: gitlab, codeowners

We have a project that has 3 parts, let's call them partA, partB, partC.
The CODEOWNERS file is configured as follows:

```
[partA]
partA/ @user1 @user2

[partB]
partB/ @user3 @user4 @user5
```

Now for these parts, the approvals work as expected, but what I would like to have, is to set up the partC so that when the changes are made there, it requires an approval from at least one codeowner from partA and at least one from partB. For example user1 approval alone would be insuficcient, also user1 and user2 approvals would not be enough, but user1 and user4 approvals would be fine.
Is it possible to set the CODEOWNERS file up to work like this?